# Get JSON content by using ajax in Firebase console

Tags: ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just created a dynamic page by using firebase console. It's working as my expectation. But instead of using javascript to retrieve data from firebase database, is there any possibilities to use `ajax` method to retrieve, edit, delete the json content, which is in firebase.

Comment: Have you read [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase expects the body to be a JSON string, so you'll need to stringify it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var param = {data: "value", data: "value"};

   $.ajax({
     url: 'https://yourdbatfirebase.firebaseio.com/.json',
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify(param),
     success: function () {
       alert("success");
     },
     error: function(error) {
       alert("error: "+error);
     }
   });
 });
```

This will accomplish the same by the way:

```
$.post('https://yourdbatfirebase.firebaseio.com/.json',
  JSON.stringify(param),
  function () {
    alert("success");
  }
);
```

Comment: By using this method, whether I need to initialize the firebase!

Comment: I'm not sure about that you can refer the firebase doc however you should have initialized firebase while making request from js?

Comment: but that answer gives you how to make request using ajax like you have asked :)

Comment: Thank you :), will check it.

Comment: Mm.. please upvote it it was pleasure to help you :)